# What effect does including async in signature (without await in body) have on program flow?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

### General question

I've just tracked down a strange behaviour to the the absence of an `async` modifier in the signature of a method. With it, I get the expected behaviour, but without it, my program behaves oddly.

The thing is, the body of the method is entirely synchronous: not a single `await` in sight. I even (as expected) get compiler warning 1998:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

The temptation then is to remove it. (I mean, the compiler is basically telling me to!) When I do remove it, I start reliably getting unexpected behaviour.

My question is: **what is async really doing when there isn't an await?**

---

### Context / specifics

*I don't think the specifics of my application will be relevant to the underlying explanation that I'm keen to understand, but I'll include it here to give some flavour...*

The program I'm developing consumes messages from a service bus. The signature of my method is:

```
public async Task<BrokeredMessage> ProcessMessageAsync(BrokeredMessage inMessage)
```

Historical context: I initially borrowed this from a similar program written by a colleague and the method name (which implies async operation) is part of an implementation of an interface.

The odd behaviour I'm experiencing when I remove the `async` modifier is that the body of the method is executed, but the message is returned as undeliverable. An interesting consequence of this is that I end up with the message being processed for each retry attempt. (I'm just lucky this was a low number!)

---

### Update

As pointed out by Mr Skeet, it is significant that, although the signature promises a return value of type `Task`, my method actually returns `null`.

Comment: @InBetween the only difference is the presence or absence of the `async` keyword.

Comment: Unless you're returning `null` from the method, I'd expect more difference than that - you'd have to change `return message;` to `return Task.FromResult(message);` or similar.

Comment: @JonSkeet As it happens, I am returning `null`. (My method is the sink at the end of a pipeline.)

Comment: Right - I would definitely add that to the question then, as the difference between returning a value (async) and returning a task-of-value (sync) is an obvious one to think about.

Comment: Good point. Edited.

Comment: This has actually suggested what might be the problem - see my edited answer. It could be not-so-mysterious after all :)

Comment: A method being `async` makes any `return` statements return a task with that value instead. So your `return null` turns into `return Task.FromResult<BrokeredMessage>(null)`. So the return value is an actual non-null task object that can be consumed properly. That is different than returning an unwrapped `null` from a non-async method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is: what is async really doing when there isn't an await?

In terms of observable behaviour:

- The code will still run synchronously, as the warning says
- The result (including any exception thrown) will be wrapped up in a `Task`

In terms of implementation, the compiler will generate a state machine to handle all the async-ness. That *shouldn't* change any other behaviour though.

I can't immediately think of any reason you'd see this message behaviour, unless it's a difference due to the handling of exceptions. If the calling code is catching an exception but ignoring a faulted task (or vice versa) that could definitely explain a difference. My first diagnostic step would be to add some logging to see whether the method *does* complete successfully or whether an exception is thrown somewhere.

Now you've stated that you're returning `null`, that's a definite difference from the caller's perspective: there's a huge difference between a method returning a `null` value for `Task<BrokeredMessage>`, and a method returning a `Task<BrokeredMessage>` with a `null` value for its `Result` property. Perhaps the caller is dereferencing the returned value, and a `NullReferenceException` is being thrown?

If that *is* the case, your first port of call should be to work out why you haven't been able to see that exception before - it suggests there's some logging missing. You can then fix it by changing this:

```
return null;
```

to

```
return Task.FromResult<BrokeredMesage>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm much clearer about async and return types now. Your suggestion to return a `Task` with a `null` result works perfectly.